How to remove duplicates with the same elements from a list?
list ={{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {4, 3}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 3}, {4, 
   2}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}, {{1, 4}, {3, 2}}, {{2, 1}, {3, 4}}, {{2, 
   1}, {4, 3}}, {{2, 3}, {1, 4}}, {{2, 3}, {4, 1}}, {{2, 4}, {1, 
   3}}, {{2, 4}, {3, 1}}, {{3, 1}, {2, 4}}, {{3, 1}, {4, 2}}, {{3, 
   2}, {1, 4}}, {{3, 2}, {4, 1}}, {{3, 4}, {1, 2}}, {{3, 4}, {2, 
   1}}, {{4, 1}, {2, 3}}, {{4, 1}, {3, 2}}, {{4, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{4, 
   2}, {3, 1}}, {{4, 3}, {1, 2}}, {{4, 3}, {2, 1}}}

How to remove duplicates with the same elements from a list?
such as:
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {4, 3}},{{3, 4},{1, 2}},{{4, 3},{1, 2}}

In the example above, both the left and right lists contain duplicates. Any list with the same elements inside the curly braces is considered a duplicate, regardless of their order. How can we remove duplicate lists and retain only one unique instance?
In other words, all the lists in the example are considered the same. We should keep only one copy and remove all other duplicates.
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}} == {{1, 2}, {4, 3}} == {{3, 4}, {1, 2}} == {{4, 
   3}, {1, 2}}

I hope to achieve this result as follows:
{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}}


At what level are you wanting to delete duplicates?

Is {{1, 4}, {3, 2}} also a duplicate of your exmaple?

What would be your desired output from ‘list’?

DeleteDuplicates has a 2-argument form in which the first argument is the structure to be deduplicated and the second is the sameness test to be applied to elements.  If I had the time I might try to figure it out for you ...

@rhermans looks like my interpretation was wrong :D. I deleted my answer.

DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, Map[Sort]]

Or maybe
DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, Sort@*Flatten]


DeleteDuplicates @ Map[Sort,list,{1,2}]

(* {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}} *)


Union[Map[Sort, MapAt[Sort, list, {All, All}]]]
(* {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}} *)


I think this is what you mean:
DeleteDuplicates[list, Length[# ⋂ #2] ≥ 1 &]
(* {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 1}, {4, 3}}, {{3, 1}, {4, 2}}, {{3, 2}, {4, 1}}} *)

Or maybe:
DeleteDuplicates[list, Length[# ⋂ Catenate[Permutations /@ #2]] ≥ 1 &]
(* {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}} *)

